# using string.replace before and after JSON.stringify brings different results

Tags: javascript, json, string

The following code example shows unexpected behavior of `replace` method:

```js
let str = "some long string\nwith line\nbreaks"
console.log(str.replace(/\n/g,''))
str = JSON.stringify(str)
console.log(str.replace(/\n/g,''))
```

I see that there are some warnings about the usage of `JSON.stringify` in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#issue_with_plain_json.st%5B%E2%80%A6%5Dify_for_use_as_javascript) and there is a seven-years-old discussion of similar issues [here](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/string-prototype-replace-problems-with-json-stringify-and-serialization-of-objects).

What exactly does `JSON.stringify` do to the string that the replace does not work the same way?

Comment: `JSON.parse(str).replace(/\n/g,'')` Your string is serialized, it's now a string that contains a string. Parse it to get back the original

Comment: Why are you using `JSON.stringify` on a string? There are entirely valid reasons for doing that, but it's also something people do by mistake, so I thought it might help to check.

Comment: My colleague just used it and stumbled into this situation and I could not understand what was wrong, and yes, I also try to use `JSON.stringify` usually for serialization before writing an object into file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It changes the newline characters to the sequence `\` `n`, because literal newlines are not valid in JSON. So the `replace` afterward doesn't find any newlines, because they aren't there anymore.

You can see it by looking at the strings before and after `JSON.stringify`:

```js
function hex2(v) {
    return "0x" + v.toString(16).padStart(2, "0").toUpperCase();
}
function showCodePoints(label, str) {
    console.log(label + ":");
    for (const ch of [...str]) {
        const lit = ch === "\n" ? "<newline>" : ch === "\\" ? "<backslash>" : ch;
        const cp = hex2(ch.codePointAt(0));
        console.log(`  ${lit.padEnd(12)} (${cp})`);
    }
}
let str = "X\nY\nZ";
showCodePoints("before", str);
str = JSON.stringify(str);
showCodePoints("after", str);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Printing the message does not help to see that it was the case. Is there a way to see these changes somehow?

Comment: @FarrukhNormuradov - You can inspect the strings in the debugger, although sometimes that can be a bit confusing. I've added a code sample showing inspecting the strings another way, maybe that helped. The fundamental point is that that `"X\nY"` is a string literal defining a string with three characters: `X`, newline, and `Y`. If you pass that through `JSON.stringify`, what you get back is a string with six characters in it: `"`, `X`, backslash, `n`, `Y`, and `"`.

Comment: \* helps (not "helped")

Answer (score 0):

```js
let str = "some long string\nwith line\nbreaks"
console.log(str.replace(/\n/g,''))
str = JSON.stringify(str).replace(/\\n/g, '');
console.log(str)
```

The JSON.stringify() method converts a JavaScript object or value to a JSON string.
after stringfy the string doesn't contain a newline character (\n), but it make it (\\n). also it add " in start and end of string after stringfy.

To remove those, use .replace(/\\n/g, '') instead of .replace(/\n/g, '')